# console.log outputs a Value different when using debugger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, javascript-debugger

I have been making a sudoku solver in JavaScript. There is a very weird behaviour.
Here is the code and context:

```
solveSudoku = ()=>{
      let sectionsCopy_ =sectionsCopy

      for(let sect =0; sect< 9; sect++){
        for(let box =0; box <9; box++){
          if(sectionsCopy[sect][box] === ''){
            for(let num=1; num<=9;num++){
              if(this.isPossible(sect,box,num)){
                sectionsCopy[sect][box]=''+num
                this.solveSudoku()
                sectionsCopy[sect][box]=''

              }
            }
            return
          }
        }
      }
      debugger
      console.log(sectionsCopy)

  }
```

This is inside a class

***sectionsCopy*** is a global variable

***sectionsCopy_*** is just for debugging (to see the value of the global var easily)

***isPossible()*** is a function that determines if num is valid in that place

***sect*** is the index of the 3x3 square in Sudoku

***box*** is the index of the unit box in Sudoku

### The problem:

Consider this Sudoku:

[image: Sudoku]

When you click solve the *sectionsCopy* variable will store :

```
[
     ["2","6","" ,"4","7","" ,"5","8","1"],
     ["" ,"" ,"3","" ,"" ,"" ,"" ,"" ,"4"],
     ["" ,"1","5","" ,"" ,"8","7","6","3"],
     ["" ,"3","" ,"" ,"" ,"6","" ,"" ,"8"],
     ["4","8","9","" ,"" ,"2","3","1","" ],
     ["" ,"7","" ,"8","3","" ,"" ,"" ,"" ],
     ["6","9","" ,"3","" ,"" ,"" ,"1","" ],
     ["" ,"" ,"8","" ,"9","" ,"5","" ,"" ],
     ["" ,"" ,"7","2","" ,"" ,"" ,"9","6"]
]
```

When I run it without the debugger being on I get this result:

[image: weird behaviour]

If I turn on the debugger, I see this:

[image: debugger]

Here is side by side, the results when I dont use debugger vs when I use debugger:

[image: Comparison]

I was expecting behaviour under debugger to be the same without debugger (or else it will be useless like this case)

I tried `console.log(sectionsCopy_)` but I know arrays are immutable so it didnt matter

Comment: See that blue/purple box with the [i].... hover over it.

Comment: It says: "This value was evaluated upon expanding. it may have changed since then"
What does that mean?

Comment: Means the value there is not the same value as it was when you logged it. console lazy logs data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @epascarello note.

seems like console.log is outputting data while it's being changed.

The solution I did was

```
let solution = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sections))
console.log(solution)
```

instead of

```
console.log(sections)
```